# My iPhone only shows the Wi-Fi symbol even when I'm using data?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

I noticed when I was checking a notification the other day that even when I was using 4G or LTE data, my phone just showed the Wi-Fi symbol, even when I turned Wi-Fi fully off. I am on an iPhone 5.

Comment: Have you tried a restart?

Comment: And screenshot of top of home screen plus what you see in settings app might help.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed the same thing. I see the 5 bars then my carrier then where I would normally see LTE, 3G etc I see the wifi symbol. When wifi is turned off that symbol grays out. It used to go away. 
I can no longer tell if I am on LTE or a lesser signal.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - From Review -